# Getting Battlefield raw weapon data

Tags: battlefield-3, battlefield-4

I know you can get weapon data from symthic.com. However, i am wanting to get RAW weapon data from the game files. Symthic, claims they are getting their data from the game files. I was wondering if anyone knew how to get this information.

For battlefield 3 or 4.

---

**UPDATE @ 31 October 2013**

I posted a question on the [Symthic forums](http://forum.symthic.com/battlefield-4-technical-discussion/5691-raw-data-used-for-battlefield-4-by-symthic/) and an admin said he will be adding more information regarding the raw data soon. I will update this question when he has posted that information.

Answer (score 1):

Symthic provided [the data files for Battlefield 4](http://symthic.com/blog/?p_Data_File_Browser-6068) (but the actual link to the data appears to be dead).

---

## I don't think you can

I think it is **not** possible to get RAW gamedata of Battlefield 4. You either would have to break the law<sup>1</sup>, or ask DICE (LA) for the original data.

### Checking out the game files yourself

I have looked in the Battlefield 4 files that I have on my pc. I did find some files that I suspect store the data in them, but like almost all the game files, I couldn't open nor read these files. These are most likely datafiles that were generated when the source code were build to the actual program that runs on your computer.

For example, I found

\Battlefield 4\Data\Win32\XP0Weapons.sb

and

\Battlefield 4\Update\Xpack3\Data\Win32\XP3Vehicles.toc

I [suspect](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smallbasic/2015/02/09/how-does-a-small-basic-program-run/) that these are files that are read by the `.EXE` application when the game is started. But outside of that, there would be no other programs that can read them.

**Reverse engineering**

So if you would like to retrieve information directly out of Battlefield 4's yourself, you would have to reverse engineer these files. This however is impossible without violating [Battlefield's 4 EULA](https://media.contentapi.ea.com/content/dam/eacom/en-us/eula/eula-bf4-row-pc-8-6-13.pdf)<sup>1</sup>:

> Except to the extent permitted under applicable law, you may not decompile, disassemble, or **reverse engineer** the Software, or any component thereof, by any means whatsoever.

### So how does Symthic does it?

I'm really not sure. My guess is that either they have received some special license that allows them to reverse engineer the software, or they received the RAW game files, the original source code and data DICE (LA) created, **before** the game was *build*.

I have searched Symthic's site and forums for more information regarding their source, but I was not able to find any, except their claim that "BF4 info is taken directly from the game files". Outside of Symthic I could also not find any solid proof for accuracy and trustworthiness of Symthic's data.

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1. I am not a lawyer, this is not legal advice.</sup>

Comment: [I did find a thread](http://forum.symthic.com/battlefield-3/battlefield-3-general-discussion/1186-question-for-administrators/?highlight=data) were they mentioned scripts for extracting info from the gamefiles, but it was about Battlefield 3.